# R Shiny - calculation using data in csv and user numericInput

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a Shiny app where a user can upload a csv file, input a numeric value, add the numeric value to a specific column of data in the csv, then save the raw + calculated data in a table. I generated a simplified Shiny script below using a simple csv file.

[image]

When I try and run the app, I get the error:

*Problem with `mutate()` input `sum`.
[31mx[39m non-numeric argument to binary operator
[34mi[39m Input `sum` is `A + C`.*

I tried looking up some examples of how to fix this, but was unable to find something that utilized eventReactive() to keep the data table updated with the new calculated data. Any help is greatly appreciated.

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(

```
# Application title
titlePanel("Test"),

# Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      
        fileInput(
            inputId = "csvFile",
            label = "Upload csv file",
            accept = c(".csv")),
        
        uiOutput("C"),
        uiOutput("D"),
        
        tableOutput("modifiedData")
    
    )
)
```

server <- function(input, output) {

```
output$C <- renderUI(
    {numericInput("C", "Variable C", 0)}
    )
output$D <- renderUI(
    {numericInput("D", "Variable D", 0)}
)

userData <- eventReactive(input$csvFile,
                          {
                              
                              req(input$csvFile)
                              
                              raw_df <- read.csv(input$csvFile$datapath)
                              calc_df <- raw_df %>%
                              
                              mutate(sum = A + C)
                              
                          }) 

output$modifiedData <- renderTable({userData()})
```

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Comment: DO you mean you want to add `C`, which is a single numeric value, to all the 6 rows of column `A`?  In that case you need `mutate(sum = A + input$C)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the reactive variable `input$C`.  Also, you should make the `eventReactive` dependent on `input$C`.  Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Test"),
  
  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    
    fileInput(
      inputId = "csvFile",
      label = "Upload csv file",
      accept = c(".csv")),
    
    uiOutput("C"),
    uiOutput("D"),
    
    tableOutput("modifiedData")
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$C <- renderUI(
    {numericInput("C", "Variable C", 0)}
  )
  output$D <- renderUI(
    {numericInput("D", "Variable D", 0)}
  )
  
  userData <- eventReactive(list(input$csvFile, input$C),
                            {
                              
                              req(input$csvFile)
                              
                              raw_df <- read.csv(input$csvFile$datapath)
                              calc_df <- raw_df %>%
                                
                                mutate(sum = A + input$C)
                              
                            }) 
  
  output$modifiedData <- renderTable({userData()})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```